# How do I install my printer with Ubuntu?

Tags: printing

How do I install my printer with Ubuntu?  The printer disk is only supported by windows.

Comment: Just plug it in, and welcome to Ubuntu.

Comment: Many printers are supported by Ubuntu without installing any drivers, so there is no need for a printer disk. But if you don't tell us the which printer you have, it's difficult to give detailed instructions. Assumed it's a USB printer, did you try just to connect it?

Comment: What is the Make and Model of your printer?

Answer (score 15):

There are over 1000+ printers supported natively in Ubuntu (or for that matter any other up-to-date distribution). The 1000 supported printers is a little bit short since Linux supports A LOT more.

The steps to get your printer working in 99% of the cases is (Follow the instructions precisely to the point. Step by step without jumping any steps):

Step 1 - Turn Printer ON (If not already done)

Step 2 - Connect Printer cable to Printer (If not already done)

Step 3 - Connect other end of Printer cable to Computer with Ubuntu

Step 4 - Enjoy! ;)

NOTE - In the case your printer is not automatically found and configured go to **System Settings -> Printers** and click on the Add button to look for it manually. This method supports USB and Network printers on the same LAN. It also supports looking for the correct drivers for the printer, downloading them and basic configuration in the moment of installation.

I can show you a small percent of supported printers here:

http://www.cups.org/ppd.php

but this list is out-of-date and needs some serious refresh since many of the ones I use are not listed there.

Another great source is http://www.openprinting.org/printers which lets you quickly look in a LONGGGGG list of printers. I recommend searching by the manufaturer and then the model because trying to look for list of the manufacturer (second option below) will take a long time and since I am saying there are a lot of printers already literally plug n' play for linux then the list will be huge. I tried HP and lost count.

If this is not enough HP offers a one click software for Ubuntu to support a little over 2000+ HP printers here: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html. Note that many of them are already supported but you will get enhance support like Ink Level notices and better control for the printer for specific stuff for it.

You can even find from companies like HP, Epson an Canon an option to actually install the needed drivers from their sites. When you try to install some of the printers from this guys, if the driver is not on your Ubuntu version, you will get an option to download and install it. A case is the Epson L555 which downloads from Epson and supports Wireless printing, Wireless scanning and finding the printer on the LAN.

UPDATE - Added site list to search for the 2000+ HP printers easier: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/index.html

Comment: Step 4, enjoy, is nice to read. But not helpful. Nothing pops up on my machine, or on the printer display (HP OfficeJet 8600), and if I try to print there no printers to select between.

Comment: @MadsSkjern Did you try going to System Settings -> Printers and clicking on Add in order for Ubuntu to check for a printer in the case it is not automatically found? (I also had the case with the Epson L555, L355 and HP 1000)

Comment: That did the it  :)

Answer (score 3):

The just "plug it in" approach didn't work for me, possibly because I was running off a Live CD. There was only a "Generic printer" listed in the print dialog, and printing to it had no effect.

What helped was: go to Printers, click "Add". See my printer listed there. Select it. Click "forward". Select the default option (install an existing driver). Go through a couple of steps confirming the manufacturer and make. At this point the printer became usable.

Also, if you are offered to install "gutenprint", cancel, disconnect from the internet, and try again. For me, the "gutenprint" install always locks up, and if I choose "local" on that screen, the search never finishes either. Only if I disconnect first does it work properly.