# How to connect my Wireless Epson WF-2540 to my laptop that is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, printing, scanner

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS on my laptop a couple of months ago. I just bought a Wireless Epson WF-2540 all in one (printer, scanner, fax, and copier) a week ago. I have the printer hooked up to my desk top, my kids laptop using the network option. I can not for the life of me figure out how to get this printer working or installed onto my laptop that has Ubuntu downloaded on to it. I have tried EVERYTHING that I can think of. Can someone please explain to me step by step on how to either download or run the installation CD that came with the printer onto my laptop that is running Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you all in advance!!

Comment: Is the desktop machine to which the printer is attached running Ubuntu, Windows, or...? Please edit your question to specify.

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely unlikely that you will be able to use the proprietary tools and drivers included on the installation CD, as these are meant for Windows.

Instead, you should simply install the printer from within Ubuntu. See:

1. [How do I install my printer with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93637/how-do-i-install-my-printer-with-ubuntu)
2. [Ubuntu help on Printers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Printers)
3. [If you have a print server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu)