# lubuntu 14.10 and installing xerox phaser 3020 wifi printer?

Tags: wireless, drivers, lubuntu, printing

I am not good at linux but not totally stupid :) and i cannot install simple printer.
I did it easy on windows and now want to do the same at my netbook with lubuntu 14.10
Printer is in my home network connected with wifi.

I downloaded drivers for linux from xerox web site, unpucked to folder, there are some *.sh scripts, i click on install.sh, some asking window to run or open in terminal, so i decided to run (how can i do something else:) ) ... nothing special happened, i can say... nothing happen.

Then went to printers, add printer, i can see my printer in network printers, choose directjob through port 9100... etc... but i cannot find any driver for my printer, i can choose from some xerox printers but not mine.

Anybode did it before and have it working? Or maybe some can help me and explain what i did wrong? I searched the web but nothing helped me.

Comment: Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

Comment: @OP: Did you manage to do it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Since there were no error messages you will have to read these links to try some other things to gather some more information and narrow down the problem.

- Printers on Ubuntu. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Printers
- There are detailed steps in this answer. [How do I install my printer with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93637/how-do-i-install-my-printer-with-ubuntu)
- You say you got the driver from Xerox, but when you chose the driver to install, did you put the files on your Ubuntu machine, like in a /temp/xerox subdirectory, and did you pick the driver directory that you downloaded from Xerox? You have to tell the install program where the new drivers are for your printer.

After you try some things, update your original post at the bottom of the post to tell us what you found. Precede the update with "EDIT:".