# to add an epson fx -890 to ubuntu14.04

Tags: drivers

I need to install Epson fx 890 dotmatrix printer to Ubuntu 14.04 lts.
help needed. Actually I got the ppd file and added the printer. but the test page is not printing.

Answer (score 0):

There are over 1000+ printers supported natively in Ubuntu (or for that matter any other up-to-date distribution). The 1000 supported printers is a little bit short since Linux supports A LOT more.

The steps to get your printer working in 99% of the cases is (Follow the instructions precisely to the point. Step by step without jumping any steps):

Step 1 - Turn Printer ON (If not already done)

Step 2 - Connect Printer cable to Printer (If not already done)

Step 3 - Connect other end of Printer cable to Computer with Ubuntu

Step 4 - Enjoy! ;)

NOTE - In the case your printer is not automatically found and configured go to System Settings -> Printers and click on the Add button to look for it manually. This method supports USB and Network printers on the same LAN. It also supports looking for the correct drivers for the printer, downloading them and basic configuration in the moment of installation.

I can show you a small percent of supported printers here:

http://www.cups.org/ppd.php

but this list is out-of-date and needs some serious refresh since many of the ones I use are not listed there.

Another great source is http://www.openprinting.org/printers which lets you quickly look in a LONGGGGG list of printers. I recommend searching by the manufaturer and then the model because trying to look for list of the manufacturer (second option below) will take a long time and since I am saying there are a lot of printers already literally plug n' play for linux then the list will be huge. I tried HP and lost count.

If this is not enough HP offers a one click software for Ubuntu to support a little over 2000+ HP printers here: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html. Note that many of them are already supported but you will get enhance support like Ink Level notices and better control for the printer for specific stuff for it.

You can even find from companies like HP, Epson an Canon an option to actually install the needed drivers from their sites. When you try to install some of the printers from this guys, if the driver is not on your Ubuntu version, you will get an option to download and install it. A case is the Epson L555 which downloads from Epson and supports Wireless printing, Wireless scanning and finding the printer on the LAN.

UPDATE - Added site list to search for the 2000+ HP printers easier: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/index.html

Copied from Luis Alvarado 
Source : [How do I install my printer with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93637/how-do-i-install-my-printer-with-ubuntu)