# How to hook up an Epson XP-430 printer to an Ubuntu 14.04 system?

Tags: printing

My son-in-law installed an Ubuntu 14.04 system on my computer - I don't know much about it myself.  I bought an Epson XP-430 printer a few days ago and cannot install the required drivers for the printer/scanner to work.  How can I hook up the printer and scanner to the computer so that I can printer and scan to my computer?

Comment: Download and install drivers from Epson site. http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Comment: Also Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/93637/how-do-i-install-my-printer-with-ubuntu

Comment: Are you trying to connect it with a USB cable? Or over the network? Have you tried going to System Settings > Printers and adding it there?

Answer (score 0):

maybe if I add the details for you Brandi:

go here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=55539&DSCCHK=5ef6ec128765534a989152269045f12fc58077f2 for the printer driver; you need to know if you have 32bit or 64bit ubuntu installed: maybe check with son-in-law? .. either way, it is epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.13-1lsb3.2**_i386.deb** or epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.13-1lsb3.2**_amd64.deb**  ... I have highlighted the two different, endings .......

for the scanner, go here http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php?version=1.3.18 and again, you need to know which version of 14.04 you are using